# Why i cannot make vector in c++ class

Tags: c++, vector

Can someone explain me why I can make a vector in the **int main()**, like this:

```
std:: vector<double> a(20);
```

but I cannot use this while i am creating a c++ class:

```
class A
{
    std:: vector<double> a(20);
}
```

Comment: Where is the main bit?

Comment: `a(20)` is calling a constructor and initializing `a`. In c++ you can't initialize class members until your constructor gets called.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the vector is in an *object* (= class *instance*), not in the class itself.

Comment: This is valid in C++11.

Comment: It won't compile because first of all, its missing the semi colon after the closing bracket of your class....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialize the vector in `A`'s constructor:

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
  std::vector<double> a;
 public:
  A() : a(20) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor that initializes the vector in order to get the behavior you want. (Also I see some syntax mistakes that need to be corrected in the question.) The class will end up looking something like this:

```
#include<vector>

class A{
    public://make the constructor public
        A():a(20)//initialize the vector in the constructors initialization list
        {}

        std::vector<double> a; //can be public or private depending on your use case
}; //don't forget the trailing semicolon!!!
```